# How to use GWT with Apache Shiro hashed and salted

Tags: mysql, gwt, salt, shiro

In this small tutorial I show you how to build a GWT Module which is responsible for registration and login.

The password gets hashed with Sha256 and salted.

Comment: since when is SO a place to submit tutorials ?

Comment: I did a lot of research and it did me take a very long time to find out how shiro works with gwt. The same goes for salted passwords. I did not find something like my tutorial on the internet. So I thought i want to share my knowledge. And that's what stackoverflow is all about. Isn't it?

Comment: It is better to reformulate your announcement into a question (which you then answer yourself). As mentioned already SO is not a place to dump tutorials or blog about your development journeys.

Comment: Even then, the tutorial aspect will remain. It is hard to phrase a precise question where your (nice!) answer will be appropriate...

Comment: thanks Veger and Lukas Eder for your clarifying how to use stackoverflow. I will keep that in mind the next time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Download and Installation

Download for Apache Shiro: http://shiro.apache.org/download.html ;
I have used Shrio-All (1.2.2 Binary Distribution) http://tweedo.com/mirror/apache/shiro/1.2.2/shiro-root-1.2.2-source-release.zip

After the download include shiro-all-1.2.2.jar in your lib folder.
[image]

We can also include other .jar files which we will need later on.

1. MySQL Driver: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm (com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar)
2. SLF4J Logging: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html (slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar, slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar)
3. Apache Commons Beanutils: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/ (commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar)

Don't forget to add your jars to your build path.

## web.xml

Add this to your web.xml

```
<!-- Apache Shero -->
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- Make sure any request you want accessible to Shiro is filtered. /* catches all -->
<!-- requests. Usually this filter mapping is defined first (before all others) to -->
<!-- ensure that Shiro works in subsequent filters in the filter chain: -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

## shiro.ini

Put your  shiro.ini into WEB-INF:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /Login.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
authc.successUrl  = /Leitfaden.html
logout.redirectUrl = /login.html

# ------------------------
# Database

# Own Realm
jdbcRealm = leitfaden.login.server.MyRealm

# Sha256
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
# base64 encoding, not hex in this example:
sha256Matcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
sha256Matcher.hashIterations = 1024

jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

# User Query
# default is "select password from users where username = ?"
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password, salt FROM USER WHERE email = ?

# Connection 
ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = root
ds.password = root
ds.databaseName = leitfaden
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds

authc.usernameParam = email
authc.passwordParam = password
authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

# Use Built-in Chache Manager
builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[urls]
/yourMainUrl.html = authc
```

## GWT Module

Create a module for login. Module name “Login” and Package name “leitfaden.login”:

Add this to your web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>leitfaden.login.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/leitfaden.login.Login/LoginService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**LoginService.java**

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("LoginService")
public interface LoginService extends RemoteService {
    public Boolean isLoggedIn();
    public Boolean tryLogin(String email, String password, Boolean rememberMe);
    public void logout();
    public void registrate(String email, String password);
}
```

**LoginServiceAsync.java**

```
public interface LoginServiceAsync {
    public void isLoggedIn(AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback);
    public void tryLogin(String email, String password, Boolean rememberMe, AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback);
    public void logout(AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
    public void registrate(String email, String password, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}
```

**LoginServiceImpl**

```
public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements LoginService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4051026136441981243L;
    private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(LoginServiceImpl.class);

    private org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject currentUser;

    public LoginServiceImpl() {
        Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory();
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isLoggedIn() {
        currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean tryLogin(String username, String password, Boolean rememberMe) {
        // get the currently executing user:
        currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        // let's login the current user so we can check against roles and
        // permissions:
        if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
             //collect user principals and credentials in a gui specific manner 
            //such as username/password html form, X509 certificate, OpenID, etc.
            //We'll use the username/password example here since it is the most common.
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username,password);
             //this is all you have to do to support 'remember me' (no config - built in!):
            token.setRememberMe(rememberMe);

            try {
                currentUser.login(token);
                log.info("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal().toString() + "] logged in successfully.");
                return true;
            } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                log.info("There is no user with username of "
                        + token.getPrincipal());
            } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) {
                log.info("Password for account " + token.getPrincipal()
                        + " was incorrect!");
            } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
                log.info("The account for username " + token.getPrincipal()
                        + " is locked.  "
                        + "Please contact your administrator to unlock it.");
            } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                log.error(ae.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void logout() {
        currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        currentUser.logout();
    }

    @Override
    public void registrate(String email, String plainTextPassword) {
        RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
        Object salt = rng.nextBytes();

        // Now hash the plain-text password with the random salt and multiple
        // iterations and then Base64-encode the value (requires less space than Hex):
        String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(plainTextPassword, salt,1024).toBase64();

        User user = new User(email, hashedPasswordBase64, salt.toString(), 0);
        this.createUser(user);
    }

    private void createUser(User user) {
        UserDAL.connect();

        UserDAL.beginTransaction();
        new UserDAL().createUser(user);
        log.info("User with email:" + user.getEmail() + " hashedPassword:"+ user.getPassword() + " salt:" + user.getSalt());
        UserDAL.commitTransaction();

        UserDAL.disconnect();
    }

}
```

## MyRealm.java

Users can now register at this application. But Shiro does not know how to compare salted passwords with the given user input. For that we need to implement our own Realm. A Realm is essentially a security-specific [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object).

MyRealm.java gets the user with the given email and returns a SaltedAuthenticationInfo. With that SaltedAuthenticationInfo Shiro knows how to compare the user input with the user from the database.

```
public class MyRealm extends JdbcRealm {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRealm.class);

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        // identify account to log to
        UsernamePasswordToken userPassToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        final String username = userPassToken.getUsername();

        if (username == null) {
            log.debug("Username is null.");
            return null;
        }

        // read password hash and salt from db
        final PasswdSalt passwdSalt = getPasswordForUser(username);

        if (passwdSalt == null) {
            log.debug("No account found for user [" + username + "]");
            return null;
        }

        // return salted credentials
        SaltedAuthenticationInfo info = new MySaltedAuthentificationInfo(username, passwdSalt.password, passwdSalt.salt);

        return info;
    }

    private PasswdSalt getPasswordForUser(String username) {
        User user = getUserByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new PasswdSalt(user.getPassword(), user.getSalt());
    }

    private User getUserByEmail(String email) {
        UserDAL.connect();
        User user = new UserDAL().getUserByEmail(email);
        UserDAL.disconnect();
        return user;
    }

    class PasswdSalt {
        public String password;
        public String salt;

        public PasswdSalt(String password, String salt) {
            super();
            this.password = password;
            this.salt = salt;
        }
    }

}
```

MySaltedAuthentificationInfo
Important is that you decode the salt correctly in getCredentialsSalt().I have used Base64.

```
public class MySaltedAuthentificationInfo implements SaltedAuthenticationInfo {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2342452442602696063L;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String salt;

    public MySaltedAuthentificationInfo(String username, String password, String salt) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    @Override
    public PrincipalCollection getPrincipals() {
        PrincipalCollection coll = new SimplePrincipalCollection(username, username);
        return coll;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSource getCredentialsSalt() {
        return  new SimpleByteSource(Base64.decode(salt)); 
    }

}
```

Users can now register and login. You would only need to code views in your login module that call the LoginService.

Comment: Does it take into account, that the salt is a binary string and can contain `\0` characters? Especially the storing in the database could be a problem, but i cannot judge this.

Comment: i have not thought about that. But I didn't have problems with the storing in the database. In MySQL it worked fine.